# How to convert crystal report to .pdf without replace the previous .pdf file?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Any ideas how to convert crystal report to .pdf without replace the previous .pdf file? I did put "Hour,Minute, Second" but it still replace the previous one. Thanks.

```
//String reportDate = dt.Year.ToString() + dt.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
String reportPrefix = dt.Year.ToString() + dt.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Millisecond.ToString();
String report = Report + "BillingReport-" + reportPrefix + ".pdf";
crRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, report);
Console.WriteLine("" + report + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
```

Comment: Your file naming scheme should depend on the way you plan to access the files once they are generated. If these are only temporary files whose file names will be presented to the user immediately then compentent_tech's solution should prove useful. Alternatively if the file names will ever need to be found or discovered by a person manually then you should consider a more logical naming scheme (something the user my know or could possibly guess).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GUID or the Ticks from DateTime.Now.

Alternatively, you could add an index if the file was previously found:

```
        String reportPrefix = Report + "BillingReport-" + dt.Year.ToString() + dt.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Day.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + dt.Millisecond.ToString();
        String report;

        bool fDone = false;
        int wIndex = 0;

        // Cycle looking for the first file that doesn't exist
        do while (!fDone) {
            report = reportPrefix;
            // Include the index once we have checked the base file name
            if (wIndex > 0)
            {
                report += wIndex.ToString();
            }
            report += ".pdf";

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(report))
            {
                // If the file exists, increment the index and keep looking
                wIndex++;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, we are done
                fDone = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I already use "static DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;" and i'm not really familiar with GUID, but will try to search it..if u have any example about the code, will be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: competent_tech, thanks..but still got the same problem if I re-run my app. Don't know why it happen.It should be not replace because the file will be diffrent by minute n second.